# How can I provide a authentication certificate to all the widgets in a widget tree after the landing page and have the navigator still working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a app where I want to check if a user is logged in and if not I build a certain widget tree. So if the user's auth state changes it rebuilds the entire tree. So you land on the splash page and the splash page waits until it knows if you logged in and either returns the RegisterPage or the GroupManagementPage which is basically a page where you can see all your groups kinda like whatsapp but instead of conversations you have groups. The problem is I just can't figure out how to do this properly.

I am using firebase auth and what I currently do is I provide a AuthenticationProvider all the way from outside my main app. In my splash page I use this provider's stream (which is basically the onAuthChanged from firebase but mapped to a AuthenticationCertificate) in a stream builder I wait until the stream is active before I build the rest of my widget tree. If the stream is active I provide my AuthenticationCertificate to the GroupManagementPage.

So that's working but problems arise with the navigator. Because in my MainApp() I defined my splash page as my home route. So now whenever I pop a route I go back to the splash page, which is not what I want. I also noticed that there are some pages which do not get provided with the AuthenticationCertificate. I am not sure why yet because the Navigator also passes the context, still have to look into that.

Now my question is how can I get this working properly so that the AuthenticationCertificate is passed to all the widgets that get navigated to from the GroupManagementPage and when the user logs out it goes back to the RegisterPage? Is this the right approach and how could I make this work?

**Main app**

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<PreferencesProvider>(
        create: (_) => PreferencesProvider()),
    Provider<AuthenticationProvider>(create: (_) => AuthenticationProvider(),),
    Provider<GroupProvider>(create: (_) => GroupProvider()),
    Provider<UserProvider>(
      create: (_) => UserProvider(),
    ),
  ],
  child: Consumer<PreferencesProvider>(
    builder: (context, preferences, _) => MaterialApp(
      home: TheSplashPage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        TheRegisterPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) =>
            TheRegisterPage(),
        TheGroupManagementPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) =>
            TheGroupManagementPage(),
        TheGroupPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => TheGroupPage(),
        TheSettingsPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) =>
            TheSettingsPage(),
        TheProfilePage.routeName: (BuildContext context) =>
            TheProfilePage(),
        TheGroupCreationPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) =>
            TheGroupCreationPage(),
      },
      theme: preferences.isDarkMode
          ? DarkTheme.themeData
          : LightTheme.themeData,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ),
  ),
);
```

**Splash Page**

```
class TheSplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const int loadTimeInSeconds = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider =
        Provider.of<AuthenticationProvider>(context);
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: loadTimeInSeconds)),
        builder: (context, delaySnapshot) {
          return StreamBuilder<UserAuthenticationCertificate>(
            stream: authenticationProvider.authenticationStream(),
            builder: (context, certificateSnapshot) {
              if (delaySnapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done &&
                  certificateSnapshot.connectionState ==
                      ConnectionState.active) {
                return Scaffold(
                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'This is the splash page',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                if (certificateSnapshot.hasData) {
                  return Provider<UserAuthenticationCertificate>.value(
                    value: certificateSnapshot.data, 
                    child: TheGroupManagementPage(),
                  );
                } else {
                  return TheRegisterPage();
                }
              }
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

**Stream in the authentication provider**

```
  Stream<UserAuthenticationCertificate> authenticationStream()
  {
    return _authentication.onAuthStateChanged.map((firebaseUser) => UserAuthenticationCertificate.fromFirebase(firebaseUser));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [StreamProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html) instead of Provider if you want to use Stream. But I don't know why you'd like to use Stream for such a case. Why not ChangeNotifierProvider?

Navigate to your pages with `Navigator.of(context)`. The navigation part of your code is strange. You return TheGroupManagementPage() or TheRegisterPage() in the build function of TheSplashPage(). This is not how Navigator works. You should use methods of Navigator like `push`, `pop`, `pushNamed` etc.

```
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(TheGroupManagementPage.routeName);
```

> So now whenever I pop a route I go back to the splash page, which is not what I want.

You can remove SplashPage from the navigation tree after login. This is one approach and not a bad approach. You should use `pushReplacement` or `pushReplacementNamed` when you push your page after auth. You can also use it for logout to replace your navigator tree with RegisterPage().

Or if you have a home screen, like a root route after splash, in your case this might be TheGroupManagementPage. Then wrap **TheGroupManagementPage** in a **WillPopScope** and do what you will inside **onWillPop**. I'd prefer the first approach though.

Comment: I chose to use a stream because the onAuthChanged is also a stream and I want the app to listen to that stream for any changes. Could I use a ChangeNotifierProvider with the onAuthChanged stream? I also couldn't really figure out how to get the ConnectionState of a stream using a StreamProvider. So the code I need to decide which widget tree I am going to show.

Comment: Yes, you can use ChangeNotifierProvider with that stream. See https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-firebase-login-using-provider-package-54ee4e5083c7

Comment: Okay I wish I found that tutorial earlier! I understand now, looks great. Thank you so much, I honestly did not know how to do this!